# Oracle transpose rows into columns for multiple aggregate values

Tags: sql, oracle

I know how to transpose rows into columns for a single aggregate value using pivot. How can I do it for multiple aggregate values? I want new_orders_count, new_orders_total, updated_orders_count, and updated_orders_total.

Orders Table

```
  date        type      total 
--------     -------   -------
03/04/14       NEW      111.11  
03/05/14      UPDATE    45.37
```

I want output in below format

```
  Date         new_count    new_total   updated_count  updated_total
--------      ----------   -----------  -------------  -------------
03/04/14           1          111.11           0          0.00
03/05/14           0          0.00             1         45.37
```

Is this output possible, would be very thankful if someone can provide query with example. My query for single aggregate is:

```
SELECT order_date, new_orders_count, updated_orders_count
FROM(
    select order_date, order_type, count(*) as order_count
    from orders
    group by order_date, order_type
    order by order_date, order_type
)
PIVOT (
    sum(order_count) FOR order_type IN ('NEW' new_orders_count, 'UPDATE' updated_orders_count)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have more than one aggregate in the `PIVOT` clause, separated by commas, [as the syntax diagram shows](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55233). As long as you want the same `FOR` and `IN` clauses, anyway.

So you can specify two sums:

```
SELECT order_date, new_count, new_total, updated_count, updated_total
FROM (
    select order_date, order_type,
      count(*) as order_count, sum(total) as total
    from orders
    group by order_date, order_type
    order by order_date, order_type
)
PIVOT (
    SUM(order_count) AS "COUNT", SUM(total) AS "TOTAL"
    FOR order_type IN ('NEW' AS "NEW", 'UPDATE' as "UPDATED")
);

ORDER_DATE  NEW_COUNT  NEW_TOTAL UPDATED_COUNT UPDATED_TOTAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ------------- -------------
05-MAR-14                                    1         45.37 
04-MAR-14           1     111.11
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b79b80/1)